# passing data from C # to Python using Memory Mapped Files

Tags: python, c#

I have an image that I want to transfer from C# to Python for processing. I pre-converted the image to byte [] and placed it in memory using a MemoryMappedFile and a MemoryMappedViewStream. Their C# to C# transfer is successful, but how do I accept a file located in memory in python?

C#

```
    using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("testmap", 2000000))
    {
        bool mutexCreated;
        Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "testmapmutex", out mutexCreated);
        using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
        {
            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
            writer.Write(imageasbyte.Length);
        }
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
       }
```

Python:

```
import mmap

mymap = mmap.mmap(fileno=-1 ,tagname='testmap', length=2000000, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)

p2 = mymap.read_byte()
p3 = mymap.read_byte()
```